# Exponential Equation $4^{1-x}-4^{1+x}+16^{x}+16^{-x}=7$

Tags: polynomials

Solve equation

$$4^{1-x}-4^{1+x}+16^{x}+16^{-x}=7$$

My attempt so far
$$4\times 4^{-x}-4\times 4^{x}+4^{2x}+4^{-2x}=7$$ 
Multiplied both sides of equation with
$$4^{2x}$$
And got
$$4^{4x}-4\times 4^{3x}-7\times 4^{2x}+4\times 4^{2x}+4\times 4^{x}+1=0$$
And substitute 
$$4^{x}=t.$$
But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Your equation is not a polynomial.

Comment: After the substitution, you have $t^4-4t^3-3t^2+4t+1=0.$

Comment: You have a typo. You have an extra $4\times 4^{2x}$ in there. It should be $$4^{4x}-4\times 4^{3x}-7\times 4^{2x}+4\times 4^x + 1 = 0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** If $t=4^x$ your equation becomes
$$4(\frac{1}{t}-t)+t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}=7$$

Set $s=\frac{1}{t}-t$ then $s^2=t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}-2$ and hence
$$4s+s^2+2=7$$

Solve for $s$ and then solve for $t$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$. So, you can rewrite:

$$4^{4x}-4\cdot 4^{3x}-7\cdot 4^{2x}+4\cdot 4^x+1 = t^4-4t^3-7t^2+4t+1 = 0$$

We try factoring into two quadratics:

$$(t^2+at+1)(t^2+bt+1) = t^4+(a+b)t^3+(2+ab)t^2+(a+b)t+1$$

or

$$(t^2+at-1)(t^2+bt-1) = t^4+(a+b)t^3+(ab-2)t^2-(a+b)t+1$$

Equating coefficients, you find $a=-5,b=1$ works for the second choice.

Thus, you have:

$$t^2-5t-1=0, t^2+t-1=0$$

This gives solutions:

$$t = \dfrac{5\pm \sqrt{29}}{2}, \dfrac{-1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Since $t=4^x>0$, it must be the positive solutions.

$$x = \dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{5+\sqrt{29}}{2}\right)}{\ln 4},\dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}{\ln 4}$$